# How to you find out what a matrix does to an equation.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, transformation, linear-transformations

Lets say I have an equation of a plane, $$x-3y+2z=0 $$

and I get matrix to transform it with say a 3x3 matrix with just a-i as place holders for the values in the matrix.

How would I find what the image of the plane is under the matrix transformation, also If there would be a different method for a function of one variable please let me know, I really dont seem to understand how to apply matrix transformations to equations.

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729799/linear-transformation-of-a-subspace).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can write the plane $x - 3 y + 2 z = 0$ as

$$\pmatrix{1 & -3 & 2} \pmatrix{x\\y\\z} = 0,$$

that is, as the kernel of the covector $\omega \in (\Bbb R^3)^*$ given in the standard basis by $\pmatrix{1 & -3 & 2}$. An (invertible) matrix $A \in GL(3, \Bbb R)$ acts on covectors by $A \cdot \omega := \omega \circ A^{-1}$ (i.e., via the contragredient representation), so the transformed plane is
$$\pmatrix{1 & -3 & 2} A^{-1} \pmatrix{x\\y\\z} = 0.$$
If one writes $A$ in terms of its components $a_{ij}$ and expands, one recovers an equation of the form $a x + b y + c z = 0$. Since we may scale both sides of the equation without changing the plane, and multiplying both sides by $\det A$ replaces the above equation with 
$$\pmatrix{1 & -3 & 2} \operatorname{adj}(A) \pmatrix{x\\y\\z} = 0 ,$$
where $\operatorname{adj}(A)$ denotes the adjugate matrix of $A$, which is typically nicer than the inverse.

Comment: thanks, this is helping, I just need to try and work with what you gave me, much appreciated

Comment: You're welcome, I'm glad you find it useful. You might find it instructive to compare this approach with the "forward" approach, that is, picking a basis $(E_1, E_2)$ for the plane, applying the matrix to get vectors $A E_1, A E_2)$, and forming the plane $(A E_1, A E_2)$. One can check that (1) this plane is independent of the choice of basis, and (2) this plane defines the same plane that the "dual" approach in my answer does.

Comment: I should emphasize that this method manifestly only works for *invertible* matrices $A$, which maps planes to planes. If $A$ is not invertible, it can map the plane to another plane, to a line, or to the origin. (In this case, though, we can still use the "forward" approach from my previous comment.)